# How to diff file's apostrophe text in PHP

Tags: php, file, diff

I want to diff 2 files and ignore checking lines that doesn't have apostrophe ("text") in PHP

For example:
File 1:

```
START
    LTEXT "Tool Version:", IDC_STATIC, 70, 150, 80, 10, SS_RIGHT
        EDITTEXT IDC_STATIC_TIME, 155, 50, 210, 10, ES_LEFT
```

File 2:

```
/*
 *    Translated by Saibamen
 *
 /

START    
    LTEXT "Wersja narzędzia:", IDC_STATIC, 70, 150, 80, 10, SS_RIGHT
        EDITTEXT IDC_STATIC_TIME, 155, 50, 210, 10, ES_LEFT
```

I want to check if there's any difference between Tool Version: and Wersja narzędzia: strings.

Note: Files doesn't have this same schemas line by line - I want to start diff lines from line that have START in file.

Comment: Have you tried anything? and if so, please include it in your question

Comment: Both lines that you have posted doesn't have start in them. Can you please clarify your question

Comment: @Epodax: Diff class by stephenmorley.org but this class make diff line by line and there's no option to set searched text to check ("some text")

Comment: convert string to array and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Chek http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get content of each file and then use `preg_match` function with proper pattern to find version line and version string.

```php
$fileContent1 = <<<TXT
dummy
dummy
LTEXT "Tool Version:", IDC_STATIC, 70, 150, 80, 10, SS_RIGHT EDITTEXT IDC_STATIC_TIME, 155, 50, 210, 10, ES_LEFT


dummy
TXT;

$fileContent2 = <<<TXT
dummy
LTEXT "Wersja narzędzia:", IDC_STATIC, 70, 150, 80, 10, SS_RIGHT EDITTEXT IDC_STATIC_TIME, 155, 50, 210, 10, ES_LEFT
dummy
dummy

TXT;

function diff_versions($leftContent, $rightContent) {
    $diff = true;
    $leftVersion = null;
    $rightVersion = null;

    $pattern = '/LTEXT "(Tool Version|Wersja narzędzia):", (.*)\R?/';

    if (preg_match($pattern, $leftContent, $matches) !== 1) {
        throw new Exception('Left content has no version line.');
    }

    $leftVersion = $matches[2];

    if (preg_match($pattern, $rightContent, $matches) !== 1) {
        throw new Exception('Right content has no version line.');
    }

    $rightVersion = $matches[2];

    return array(
        'diff' => $leftVersion === $rightVersion,
        'leftVersion' => $leftVersion,
        'rightVersion' => $rightVersion,
    );
}

var_dump(diff_versions($fileContent1, $fileContent2));
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
   'diff' => boolean true
   'leftVersion' => string 'IDC_STATIC, 70, 150, 80, 10, SS_RIGHT EDITTEXT IDC_STATIC_TIME, 155, 50, 210, 10, ES_LEFT' (length=89)
   'rightVersion' => string 'IDC_STATIC, 70, 150, 80, 10, SS_RIGHT EDITTEXT IDC_STATIC_TIME, 155, 50, 210, 10, ES_LEFT' (length=89)
```

And then you should diff versions as you like.

Comment: Thanks! One question. How to multiple output for all file content (for)? I use file_get_contents() and this output me only first match. I already changed pattern to `$pattern = '/(LTEXT|PUSHBUTTON|CAPTION|GROUPBOX|RTEXT) "(.*)"(.*)\R?/';`

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` instead if you want to find and extract multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give a point to start with:

```
$str1 = 'LTEXT "Tool Version:", IDC_STATIC, 70, 150, 80, 10, SS_RIGHT
    EDITTEXT IDC_STATIC_TIME, 155, 50, 210, 10, ES_LEFT';

$str2 = 'LTEXT "Wersja narzędzia:", IDC_STATIC, 70, 150, 80, 10, SS_RIGHT
    EDITTEXT IDC_STATIC_TIME, 155, 50, 210, 10, ES_LEFT';

$shortStr1 = substr($str1, 23);
$shortStr2 = substr($str2, 28);

echo "\n";
echo substr_compare($shortStr1, $shortStr2, 0, strlen($shortStr1));
echo "\n";
echo substr_compare($shortStr2, $shortStr1, 0, strlen($shortStr2));
```

- Two compares if the Strings are not the same size
- Will return 0 if same
- Will return 1 if not same
- For a better test you have to test via [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) and [pre_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

I think this - or at least the idea - will lead you to the answer.
Next time provide more Information and what you already have tried and many people here will even provide full solutions!
But for that you have to show what you already got and already tried. No one wants to do the work you are paid for, but many here are willing to help you, if you have any problem **and** tried hard enough!

Comment: Oh look, you already has an solution posted by @Jan.J while I was writing this!